# Open source "deployment tool" required to deploy EAR, WAR files to any hosted servers

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, open-source, webserver, web-deployment

A deployment tool to deploy both **EAR, WAR** files present in local 'build box' to any hosted servers (i.e. testing or staging servers).

Currently .sh scripts are run on every server for deployment.

**Environment:** 
Linux, Java EE application (ATG framework to be precise), **Jboss** servers used.

Deployment tool Requirement:

1) software must be an open source.

2) Only a deployment tool required; with NO build tool and continuation integration tools attached to it like the Jenkin or Hudson application's have.

3) The software must be a light weight GUI application (even plugins are OK for eclipse, or for any SVN).

4) The software must also have capability to look into SVN.

5) And most importantly it must be fault tolerant; i.e must have back-up copies and version controls if deployment goes wrong.

I know all the above are a little big ask. I am not sure if 'cruise control' application will do all above work, suggestions about it will be appreciated.

I have researched to find the link http://deployment.tigris.org/; but none of them seem to have satisfied all the above requirements. Could not find such in GNU open source software's. Any Suggestions from any of them will be appreciated. Someone suggested something called 'Jeera', 'redhat' as well, but not sure about them.

**Finally to sum up in one sentence,  need an "Open source Deployment(only) tool" for above mentioned environment.**

Comment: I appreciate that sometimes the rationale behind some requirements is "just because", but why can you not use a Jenkins/Hudson job that just does a deployment task?

Comment: because they are both heavy weight software's; Jenkins in particular is more of an continuous integration tool having capability of doing many tasks. I need only deployment of EAR, WAR files. Hudson is not an open source.

Comment: Hudson is absolutely open source, run by the Eclipse foundation

Comment: ur right about being open source; my bad .... my comment for Jenkins is meant for hudson as well. i.e. being a heavy weight software and more of a continuous integration tool.

Comment: right, I figured as much, and I can understand a desire for lightweight-ness in your tools and issues you have with Hudson/Jenkins

Answer (score 3):

[Kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net) is a lightweight deployment app that is free for commercial use (but not open source)

If you can be somewhat flexible on the GUI requirement, take a look at Ning's [galaxy](https://github.com/ning/galaxy), which is open source and free (but CLI based, also has a dependency on Ruby)

Comment: Thanks,,, will see into it.

Comment: Kwatee is not properly working with jboss 7. Jboss needs an Archieved (war) file in its deployment; whereas Kwatee deployes an exploded (extracted war) folder. How to make sure Kwatee deployes war file as it is instead of deploying an extracted  folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368629/is-it-possible-to-deploy-an-exploded-war-file-unzipped-war-in-jboss-as-7

Comment: @VinayRao welcome to SO, if you feel that peter's answer is what you are looking for, please tick the answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://xebialabs.com/download/xl-deploy/ is an automation solution that agentless across all target platforms, windows and unix target. it is supporting almost all popular Java EE container like jboss, tomcat, webspshere. and the community edition is free for non-commercial user.

Cargo is another open sourced tool which support automatic deployment.