# Is it possible to deploy an exploded war file (unzipped war) in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss7.x, web-deployment

I Have no problem in deploying an **'app.war'** file when copied into the below deployments folder : 
 **"jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\jboss-as-7.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments"**; JBoss7 would deploy it properly.
I would like to do the same for an exploded folder **'app'**(i.e. extracted app.war). Apache Tomcat works properly with an exploded folder in its deployment directories, but am unable to do the same for JBoss.

I did put  **deployment-scanner auto-deploy-exploded='true'** in JBoss console; and I did create **'app.war.dodeploy'** file along with an extracted **'app'** folder in deployments directory. I am unable deploy and start the 'app' in jboss server.

**I am wondering if it is possible to deploy an exploded war file (unzipped war) in JBoss7.**

I would like to particularly deploy an unzipped folder because I am using '[Kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net/)' deployment software. Kwatee copies an exploded (extracted war) folder to its target server deployment folder. I would appreciate if anyone knows How to make Kwatee move a 'war' file as it is, instead of moving an extracted war folder. I would also appreciate if anyone can suggest an alternate software for Kwatee or [answer my previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327273/open-source-deployment-tool-required-to-deploy-ear-war-files-to-any-hosted-se)

Comment: Looks like you've got an acceptable answer there below, no?

Answer (score 32):

Rename your folder to **app.war** and touch your **app.war.dodeploy** file.

I would also recommend editing your `deployment-scanner` in the **standalone.xml** configuration file and changing `auto-deploy-exploded` property back to `false`.

From [Admin Guide - JBoss AS 7.0](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-FileSystemDeployments):

> Manual deploy mode is strongly recommended for exploded content, as exploded content is inherently vulnerable to the scanner trying to auto-deploy partially copied content.