# JBoss equivalence of glassfish alternate docroot

Tags: jsf, jboss, glassfish, jboss7.x

This is very easy using Glassfish:

Consider my absolute path on unix `/apps/static_content/`.
Using Glassfish, I will simply define *alternate doc root* as:

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1"
  value="from=/static/* dir=/apps/static_content/"/>
```

When I upload my images and other data files, I can save them to the `/apps/static_content` directory, and within my JSF page I can display my static content normally as:

```
<p:graphicsimage value="/static/external_web_app.png"/>
```

I really need to achieve the same functionality in JBoss AS7

How can I do this?

Comment: JBoss doesn't support anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Option 1: You could try to deploy a **separate exploded .war file**, and use that for your static content

In your case: In `.../jboss-7/standalone/deployments/` there must be a `static.war/`.

So the uploads go into this directory, and the content is served back the normal way.

As for details, see [Is it possible to deploy an exploded war file (unzipped war) in JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14368629/2390083)

As pointed out by BalusC: You must not redeploy/remove this directory, as soon as data has been uploaded. You should have a regular backup of this directory.

As far as I know this is the only possibility to do it **by configuration/setup only**.

---

- Option 2: Create separate webapp with name `static.war`. Add a **servlet to stream the static content**

This way there is no need to upload/store the files into the file system below `../deployments/`, it could be any directory, but you need an additional servlet, so it's solved programatically.

A simple streaming servlet could look like this (just streaming - no authentication etc.):

```
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final File dir = new File("/var/cms/storage/");
        final String start = "/static/";
        final String relativePath = request.getRequestURI().substring(
                request.getRequestURI().indexOf(start) + start.length());
        final File file = new File(dir, relativePath);
        final String ct = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
        response.setContentType(ct);

        final InputStream is = 
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        try {
            final boolean closeOs = true;
            org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy
                    (is, response.getOutputStream(), closeOs);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

Map all URLs to this servlet:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The name `static.war` provides the `/static/` web context, so that should make it compatible with the URLs in  your code.

Comment: OP intented to save uploaded files and serve them back. This doesn't go together with a WAR.

Comment: @BalusC It might not be specified/supported, and probably the data center won't like it. I've tested it, it works using an exploded .war using JBoss 7.1.1: I could upload files into that directory, and serving back works the normal way.

Comment: Until you redeploy the WAR.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, I've added this hint to the answer.

Comment: No, just do not save uploaded files in deploy folder at all. Related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page/8889096#8889096 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf/4543951#4543951

Comment: That leaves the area of "configuration only", but yes, a valid option. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Servlet gets complicated if you'd like to take caching and range requests into account as well. By the way, servlet doesn't need to be deployed in a different WAR.

Comment: I have looked at the @BalusC servlet implementation and simply modified it a little to suit my needs. So i will mark this servlet option as the answer. And since i am using the jsf2.0 implementation. i dont need to have servlet mapping in the configurations, but simply annotate my servlet class using WebServlet annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit old, but answering if someone need to do this with newer versions of JBoss/Wildfly.

JBoss AS was renamed to Wildfly from version 8 (i.e. Wildfly 8 is JBoss AS 8) and Red Hat supported version of JBoss was renamed to JBoss EAP. So this applies to:

- Wildfly (any version)
- JBoss EAP (from version 7)

First thing to note is that "Alternate doc root" feature in glassfish doesn't work like that. Please take a look at this question for an explanation of the behavior of this feature: [Alternate docroot not working on glassfish 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617517/alternate-docroot-not-working-on-glassfish-4)

Now, to answer this question, JBoss/Wildfly is build upon Undertow, that let you do exactly what you need. Refer at this question on how to configure undertow as a web server for static content: [How to configure Wildfly to serve static content (like images)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684037/how-to-configure-wildfly-to-serve-static-content-like-images)

Comment: Update your answer and add the versions that this applies to.

Answer (score 0):

If you explore jboss directory you will find that there are many you can use to store different type of data like jboss.serer.data.dir .

You can try asking this directory path via system properties and store in a folder the data your services are using, under such directory.

```
String path = System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir");
```

Then you can use *path* as you want, if is just static as shown in your example you set directly the name of the directory.

This should work, I hope :p

ps: as the previous answer suggest the saved data will keep in the directory, and you must not redeploy/remove this directory.. It will keep your data there..

Comment: how do i then access this path in my jsf page?

Comment: Use a servlet or a backing bean with a simple method that returns you the desired path..