# Alternate docroot not working on glassfish 4

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-7

Im trying to set-up an alternate docroot in order to serve uploaded documents from. I have included the following in my glassfish web xml

```
<context-root>/dom</context-root>
  <property description="Uploaded Images" name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:/Test" />
```

I have then stored a test pdf in the Test folder called cars.pdf.

To access it i am typing the following into my browser

```
http://localhost:8080/uploads/cars.pdf
```

This however simply gives me a 404 error, ive tried googling and searching about here but nothing seems to work. Can some tell me what im doing wrong?

Thanks Steve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use

```
<property description="Uploaded Images" name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:\Test\" />
```

and then drop your images into `C:\Test\uploads\`

or, for example, use

```
<property description="Uploaded Images" name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=C:\" />
```

and then drop your images into `C:\uploads\`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, the docs at oracle don't explain well what you have put up there thanks for the answer i finally have it working