# GlassFish 4.1 alternatedocroot, Access static contents

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

I need to access some images with this URL http://localhost:8080/static/img1.jpg

The images are in "/home/andrea/Documents", the application context is "/". I'm using GlassFish 4.1.1.

In the /WEB-INF directory of project I've got the following: (glassfish-web.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/static/* dir=/home/andrea/Documents" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

The problem is that, the file is not found.
What did I miss?

Is there another way to define alternatedocroot` or map a virtual directory outside the project?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617517/alternate-docroot-not-working-on-glassfish-4. Look there if the answer applies to you too.

Comment: Try go into server.log of your glassfish domain and search for an error message, you will see under what path glassfish tries to lookup the resources. I guess problem might be also in missing `/` after `Documents`

Comment: @OndrejM I've tried more times.... doesn't work... and the log doesn't log nothing.. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've resolved the problem reading this post: http://glassfish.10926.n7.nabble.com/unable-to-get-working-alternate-docroots-td40978.html

Unfortunately the documentation is not so clear, I try to explain how I solved my problem

The **dir** value is the base directory of your **alternatedocroot**, so you must put full path specified for the value **from**into the base dir of alternatedocroot. Therefore in my case the real structure is **/home/andrea/Documents/static** (Remember to insert "/" at the end of **dir** value).

### glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/static/* dir=/home/andrea/Documents/" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

## My exigence

My exigence is to have a separate directory to upload images separated from the ".war" archive. The solution I've found is insert the images in docroot directory of glassfish domain1 directory

### glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/static/* dir=./docroot/" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Remember that the real path must contain static directory: [...]/glassfish/domains/domain1/docroot/static/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you'are great my friend. It works for me, in my **Glassfish 4.1.1.**

> I had this code in my **glassfish-web.xml**, under WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/GestionProcesos</context-root>
    <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
              <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.   </description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

> But now my **glassfish-web.xml** file, I have it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/GestionProcesos</context-root>
    <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/Downloads/* dir=/Users/Cristian/" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

> So, to **download** a file in my jsp:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Downloads/FileName.pdf" download="FileName.pdf">Download file</a>
```