# How to deal with large WAR files in AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**What I have  done ?**

Developed a Web app using JSP which allows user to register , login and upload file to AWS S3. I am deploying this app to aws using Elastic Beanstalk by uploading war file of app.
For login and register modules I have used RDS and it is working fine.

**Problem**

When I want to upload files to S3 , I need to use AWS SDK jar and its supporting JAR files in WEB app.
When I finished with development part and exported war file , it was around 75  MB. So problem is that if I change anything to app , I need to upload this large size war  to aws.  Size of the war file is effected due to JAR files of AWS SDK.

**What are the options to deal with such situation ?**

Comment: you should change the uploaded content size in server configuration

Comment: This may be an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368629/is-it-possible-to-deploy-an-exploded-war-file-unzipped-war-in-jboss-as-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use build tools like Maven. This will ensure the dependency files downloaded in the server's local maven repository. So it makes the upload size of your project, reduced. [Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) is a official quick guide

Comment: That would work if the war was built on the aws server which doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: As the user wants frequent update to the code, I suggested it. If the war is deployed only on release times, the question owner would  not have worried about the big file upload

Comment: @Thanga I didn't have knowledge about Maven , after your suggestion I have tried and It worked. Thanks Man..

Answer (score 0):

The steps to deploy partial (thus smaller) war files with Elastic Beanstalk:

1. create a separate package (e.g. `dist-lib.zip`) w/ the external libraries in use
2. upload this package to S3
3. create the Elastic Beanstalk deployment `config` files for downloading and extracting the external libraries on the EC2 nodes
4. create the `war` file w/o the external libraries
5. deploy the `war` file as usual

### 1. `dist-lib.zip`

Excerpt from `build.gradle` of the web module (the version number is removed from the path within the zip):

```
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

distTar.enabled = false
distZip.enabled = hasProperty('dist') // 

def subPrjs = rootProject.subprojects.collect { it.name } - project.name

//...

distributions.main {
    contents.exclude subPrjs.collect { "$it*.jar" }
    contents.exclude "tomcat-embed-*"
    contents.exclude "tomcat-annotations-api-*"
    contents.exclude "spring-boot-starter-tomcat-*"
}

distZip {
    baseName += '-lib'
    version = null
    doLast {
        def f0 = archivePath;
        version = props.ver; // replace w/ your version number
        if (archivePath.exists()) {
            archivePath.delete()
        }
        f0.renameTo(archivePath.path)
    }
}
```

Create the zip file w/: `gradle distZip -Pdist=true`.

### 2. Upload `dist-lib.zip` to S3

From aws-cli: `aws s3 cp YOUR_MODULE/build/distributions/YOUR_MODULE-lib-YOUR_VERSION.zip s3://YOUR_BUCKET/dist/dist-lib.zip`

I'm suggesting securing the bucket:

1. it won't generate extra external traffic for you;
2. if something goes wrong and you accidentally upload some sensitive data, it won't cause any damage.

### 3. EB config

The configuration details for accessing a private S3 bucket are described in [Storing Private Keys Securely in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html).

You need the following files to automatically download, extract and add the external libraries to the extracted war package before your application is copied into Tomcat's `webapps`.

`deploy/eb/app-res.config`:

```
Resources:
  # Use instance profile to authenticate to S3 bucket that contains the private key
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-169305339676"]
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role-dev"

files:
  # distribution libs
  /tmp/dist-lib.zip:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: tomcat
    group: tomcat
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/YOUR_BUCKET/dist/dist-lib.zip
```

`deploy/eb/dist-lib.config`:

```
files:
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_lib_extr.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      rm -rf /tmp/dist-lib
      unzip  /tmp/dist-lib.zip -d /tmp/
      mv     /tmp/dist-lib/lib /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib
```

### 4. `war` package

Another part from `build.gradle` of the web module (the submodule (subproject) classes are included directly in `WEB-INF/classes`):

```
apply plugin: 'war'

jar.enabled = false

def env = project.hasProperty('env') ? project.getProperty('env') : 'lcl' // profile: set w/ "-Penv=..."
def ebDirs = ["$rootDir/deploy/eb-$env", "$rootDir/deploy/eb", "$rootDir/deploy/eb/_nginx"] // env. specific config first

// ...

war {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'fail'
    //rootSpec.exclude subPrjs.collect { "**/$it*.jar" } // exclude subproject jars only
    rootSpec.exclude "**/*.jar" // exclude dependencies => they must be downloaded and extracted during deployment
    from(subPrjs.collect { project(":$it").sourceSets.main.output }) {
        duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude' // in case of one output dir for multiple sourceSets
        into "WEB-INF/classes"
    }
    from(ebDirs) {
        duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude' // in case of env. spec. config
        exclude "**/_*"
        into ".ebextensions"
    }
}
```

### 5. Deploy

The above solution was tested w/ `gradle v4.10.2` and `aws-cli v1.16.44` (both w/ `eb create` and `eb deploy`).